# Adding Ads to a Web Page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am in the process of setting up a website and was thinking of adding a means to allow ads to be added to my front page for a cost.

I have seen some websites that seem to use like vertical cells that say "Advertise Here".

As this is all new to me, I was wondering if people can suggest a jQuery plug-in that I could use, that relates to adding ads to a web page or perhaps know of something else that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be using Jquery. This is not an advertising delivery tool

Your best best to make it easy would be to sign up to an advertising network which can supply you with ads (including the code to implement) then they will pay you for the number of impressions your site achieves. This way you do not have to source the ads yourself.

try:

http://www.valueclickmedia.com/index.shtml

http://www.infolinks.com/lp1.html?trackerid=11000640

http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB329GB329&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=advertising+networks+for+your+website

Comment: Thanks for the response Richard - just wondering if you are able to trial the ads first to see how it looks and from my end - do I need to pay them for advertising on my website?

Comment: No the point is that they pay you, have a look around there are many, if you look at sites like http://www.lipsum.com/ which do this or you can sign up with google to show their ads.